# Percentage sign getting removed when URI decoding

Tags: perl, urlencode, html-escape-characters

I'm trying to decode a uriencoded bit of form data in Perl (the encoded data is `%25admin` which *should* decode to `%admin`). I'm using some long repeated, simple regex to do it:

```
    $value =~ tr/+/ /;
    $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;    
    $value =~ s///g;
```

This set of regex has served me well for years and usually does just fine, but in this case, it is outputting `min` ("%ad" is missing from the decoded string as though it were part of the escaped character). What am I missing that it is causing it to interpret the characters `%25ad` as a single escaped character rather than `%25` as the escaped character and `ad` as independent of it?

Comment: what do you expect the s///g to do? (It almost certainly isn't doing what you want.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
```

This successfully converts `%25admin` to `%admin` which is actually the result you want. But for some unknown reason you then do another substitute with an empty pattern:

```
$value =~ s///g;
```

This empty pattern has a special meaning. From [perldoc perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators):

> **The empty pattern //**
>   If the PATTERN evaluates to the empty string, the last successfully matched regular expression is used instead.

The last successfully matched regular expression is in the line above, so this statement essentially means:

```
$value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])//g;
```

This matches `%admin` and results in `min`.

Comment: Thank you, @Steffen Ullrich. I inherited that bit of code years ago and had actually meant to refresh myself on why I had that second entry -- it didn't really make sense to me, but up until this point, it worked, so I was trying to figure out if there was something I was missing that it did. I shall remove it.

Comment: @TimothyR.Butler: *"up until this point, it worked"* - It depends on the input if the second regex causes harm or not. if you have input of `%25foobar` then the first regex will replace this with `%foobar` but the second one will not match and thus the result stays the expected `%foobar`.

Comment: yes -- I just don't think I've pushed it until this point, almost 2 decades after I put the code there.  I always get nervous removing code I can't remember the original purpose to, but I've now removed that. Thank you.